# Open tag not working in Angular 6.4.1 version

Tags: angular

I have just started learning Angual JS and following one of the tutorial for hands on.

In the example they have mentioned the below code which is not working for me. In the below example  class="btn-group open" is unable to open the drop-down. I tried using show instead of open but it didn't work.

What I suppose to do make it work?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="btn-group open">
      <button type="button" 
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">To Shopping List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing related to AngularJS (or Angular?) in the code you've provided. This looks to be plain HTML code, relying on the BootStrap CSS and JS to work as expected. Maybe we could help if we knew which tutorial you're following.

Comment: The problem lies with the bootstrap CSS version which I was using. In the tutorial they are using bootstrap version 3.4 whereas my bootstrap version is 4.3.1.

Comment: @vibhas : can u create a demo code on stackblitz.com and share us the url ? Also, share the tutorial link

Comment: I can share the github repo please check: https://github.com/vibhaskarn/AngularJS1.

Comment: Link for tutorial : https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/angular-7-formerly/9781788998437/9781788998437-video8_1